# How to delete data after 24 hours since its creation in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I Know This can be done in Google Console using buckets.
Can Someone Explain this in Detail.
Step by step.

Comment: Would something like it works for you ? https://medium.com/@fabio.sabbion/firestore-auto-delete-a-document-after-24-hours-91db9d0132a0

Comment: Please check the duplicate as it explains how you can do this. Instead of addition, you need to delete files.